# AWS: zip lambda application

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zip

I am developing AWS Lambda (NET6).
During the Github action execution (build, zip, upload) I have received the error:

```
Run zip -jr customerlambda-356e9e4b8869b2cf7f483d739aa5a8aa34e0fc13.zip -i ./bin/Release/net6.0/publish/*

zip error: Invalid command arguments (nothing to select from)
Error: Process completed with exit code 16.
```

It is in Ubuntu-latest environment.
What is incorrect here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to zip the files `./bin/Release/net6.0/publish/*`, then get rid of the `-i`. The use of `-i` is to exclude files that don't match the following pattern from the files and directories already specified.

Comment: Yes, by idea I need to zip all files from /publish folder. But if I use -i the terget zip is created and size == 20B, a later step cannot deploy it as a Lambda because its an empty/

Comment: That's what will happen with the `-i`. _Get rid of the `-i`!_